# Parse query using pointers

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

For simplicity sake, I have two classes `Location` and `Program`.  `Location` has `objectId` and `name`, while `Program` has `objectId`, `name` and `location` (which is a pointer to `Location` `ObjectId`).  When a user selects a location, how do I return the associated programs in a query? The following code doesn't work right now.

```
let pointer = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "location", objectId: passedLocationID!) //passedLocationID is a string containing the ObjectId from the selected location    

let query = PFQuery(className:"Program")
query.whereKey("location", equalTo: pointer.objectId!)
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        if let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                self.programName.append(object["name"] as! String)
                self.programID.append(object.objectId! as String)
            }
        }
    } else {
}
```

This query prints the following error to the console "pointer field location needs a pointer value"

What would the correct code be to return the associated programs?

#### EDIT

I have found a solution, but it seems like overkill.  Two queries to Parse, I feel like this should be accomplished using only 1 query.

```
let firstQuery = PFQuery(className: "Location")
firstQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: passedLocationID!)
    
let secondQuery = PFQuery(className: "Program")
secondQuery.includeKey("location")
secondQuery.whereKey("location", matchesQuery: firstQuery)
secondQuery.findObjects.......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found an answer.

When I pass the location to the program view controller, I need to pass it as a PFObject.

```
var passedLocationID: PFObject?
```

And then just a simple query works.

```
let newQuery = PFQuery(className: "Program")
newQuery.whereKey("location", equalTo: passedLocationID!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the correct answer updated for **Swift 3+** in case someone is searching:

```swift
guard let query = ProgramModel.query(), let pointerQuery = LocationModel.query() else {
   // Your parse class isn't set up correctly. Handle error.
   return
}

// You can also use other parameters like `notEqualTo` or `containedIn`.
pointerQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: passedLocationId)

// The important line is the one below, which calls the pointer query:
query.whereKey("location", matchesQuery: pointerQuery)
query.includeKey("location")
query.findObjects... or query.countObjects...
```